# Comments for Excel cells

Tags: office-js

Is it possible to add comments to Excel cells using Javascript API? 
Something like this:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: The JavaScript API seems to lack that functionality. If it would be anywhere, it would be in the `Range` object (In VBA there is a method in the range object for adding a comment). The JavaScript API version of the Range object implements just part of the functionality of VBA's. Methods for getting at the comment of the cell seems to be one of the things left out. It is possible, of course, that I overlooked something. See https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/range

Answer (score 3):

Comments API feature is part of the roadmap, but it is not available today.